# C# Modify class properties values

Tags: c#

How could I modify **all** `string` properties of a class?

Let's say I have a model that has:

- 2 x `int` properties
- 10 x `string` properties

I want to add "some text" to all of the strings.

How do i make an extension method that would take the class object, grab the string values, add some text and then return the whole object with int values unchanged and string values changed?

Comment: You'd need reflection. I'd start learning about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/viewing-type-information

Comment: Use reflection.

Comment: I would say most likely your design is wrong. Could you explain why you want to do something like that ? If you really need to add something to all strings they should be in an Array.

Comment: I used the question as an example. What I really need is to html encode each string from a class I receive as a request in my endpoint. I need it so that if someone tries to inject html code like <br>, it needs to get converted to &lt;brgt;

Answer (score 1):

```
T AppendToStringProperties<T>(T obj, string toAppend)
{
    // Get all string properties defined on the object
    var stringProperties = obj
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    // Append to the values
    foreach (var prop in stringProperties)
    {
        var val = (string)prop.GetValue(obj) ?? ""; // If value is null use an empty string
        val += toAppend;
        prop.SetValue(obj, val);
    }

    return obj;
}
```